# How to write a WHERE clause for NULL value in ARRAY type column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table which contains a column of string `ARRAY` type as:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    list text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I then added rows which contain various values for that array, including an empty array and missing data (`null`):

```
insert into test (id, list) values (1, array['one', 'two', 'three']);
insert into test (id, list) values (2, array['four']);
insert into test (id, list) values (3, array['']);
insert into test (id, list) values (4, array[]::text[]); // empty array
insert into test (id, list) values (5, null); // missing value
```

pgAdmin shows table like this:

[image: Table in pgAdmin]


I am trying to get a row which contains a null value (`[null]`) in the `list` column but:

```
select * from test where list = null;
```

...returns no rows and:

```
select * from test where list = '{}';
```

...returns row with `id = 4`.

**How to write WHERE clause which would target NULL value for column of ARRAY type?**

Comment: Hint:  `IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. That was simple and it works. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? I could close this question but someone in future might find your answer helpful.

Comment: . . No.  I voted to close the question as a simple typographical error, because this is very basic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b4e72ee8557f1879fec422b2ef1e75db)

```
... WHERE list IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select * from test where list IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test where list IS null;
```